# Using an array to take average of rolling difference in excel?

Tags: excel

Hi I need to calculate the average of a rolling difference in excel, Ideally using one formula

For example on the below data set the average of the 3day difference would be

```
 A
 1
 2 
 3
 4
 5
 8 
 9 
 1

`Average(A1-A4, A2-A5,A3-A6,A4-A7...etc)
```

Ideally I'd like build something where I can calculate the average difference between y number of days.

Is there an easier way without having to build out a difference matrix?

Comment: If you apply a bit of maths to these sort of problems I think I'm right in saying for an n-day difference you only need to consider the first and last n terms - all the middle ones cancel out.

Answer (score 0):

So my formula would look like this

```
=(SUM(INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)-2):INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)))-SUM(A1:A3))/(COUNT(A:A)-3)
```

assuming the data starts in A1 with no headers and there are at least 4 numbers.

[image]